# some stuff not printed

Tags: perl

I would like to know the reason why "00" hasn't been printed:

```
my @compass_points = ('north', 'east', 'south', 'west');
my $direction = 'north-east';
unshift @compass_points, $direction;
# @compass_points contains: north-east, north, east, south and west

print ($west = pop @compass_points)."00"; 
print "11";
push @compass_points, $new_direction; # put $west back

print @compass_points;
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` would inform you about the error.

Answer (score 5):

With [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) on, Perl would have told you.

It interprets the parentheses after `print` as surrounding the parameters to it, so the `00` is appended to the return value of `print` and thrown away, as the print appears in void context.

Either wrap all the parameters into a new pair of parentheses

```
print(($west = pop @compass_points) . '00');
```

or use `+` to tell the parser the parentheses introduce an expression:

```
print +($west = pop @compass_points) . '00';
```

You can also take advantage of print taking several parameters:

```
print $west = pop @compass_points, '00';
```